# Во всех ли случаях будет стоять запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

1) Я знаю чтО ты можешь
2) Я знаю что тЫ можешь
3) Я знаю что ты мОжешь
- да
- нет. 
И объясните почему.

Answer (score 2):

Во всех случаях запятая выделяет главное предложение от придаточного. Постановка или отсутствие запятой не зависит от логического ударения.

Запятая не ставится, если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия):

> Я бы тоже желал знать **почему** (Л. Т.); Не знаю **почему**, но я его не понимал (Триф.); Трудно сказать **почему**; Он ушёл и не сказал **куда**; Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил **когда;** Мать определяла температуру ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит **сколько**; Кто-то подал больному чашку воды, он даже не взглянул **кто;** Я не скажу **какое,** я говорю — большое несчастье.

Подробнее о запятых в придаточных предложениях, см. здесь: [Д. Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)